# Child Activity gets created from scratch after switching tabs in a TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have an annoying problem with TabActivity. I have several activities in it and when I switch between them each of them gets recreated and loses all its info :(

I've tried using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` but no luck :(

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Activities/IntentTab/) showing the use of activities in tabs that does not suffer from the problem you cite.

Even better would be to get rid of the activities and just use views as the contents of your tabs, as that will save RAM, CPU, and battery life. See [this project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab/) for a sample.

Comment: Thanks for your help. View example is too simple. Are those views created on each tab switch? Also are custom views supported?

Comment: "Are those views created on each tab switch?" No, they are created when the activity is started up. "Also are custom views supported?" Sure, no different than with any other layout.